# Condition from a string to select dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = [[1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

and from a string like this:

```
cond_str = ['col1 >= 1', 'col3 >= 1']
```

and I would like to achieve this:

```
df.loc[(df['col1'] >= 1) & (df['col3'] >= 1)]
```

Is there any simple way to do this or do I have to write my own parsing function for this?

Comment: You want ti divide your `cond_str ` list in `df.loc[(df['col1'] >= 1) & (df['col3'] >= 1)]` with some modification?

Comment: Yes I want to use the strings as actual conditions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```py
df.query("&".join(cond_str))
```

which results in

```py
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     0     1
1     1     1     1
```

Comment: Nice! For some reason I assumed  bitwise operators wouldn't work with eval or query, TIL they do :)

Comment: @yatu I thought the same the first time I encountered this, but I very much like it. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `eval` of python to evaluate a string expression. e.g. for your case

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
print(df)

    col1  col2  col3
0     1     0     1
1     1     1     1
2     0     0     1

cond_str_list = ['col1 >= 1', 'col3 >= 1']

cond_str = ' & '.join(['(df.'+i+')' for i in  cond_str_list])

print(cond_str)

df = df[eval(cond_str)]

print(df)

    col1  col2  col3
0     1     0     1
1     1     1     1
```